# Is there a way to make the functionality read-only for non-admins (AAD)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

In our scenario, users get authenticated via free Azure AD. We would like to make the modal window (AddEditForm) hidden for all non-admins. Since it's only a couple of admins, it's OK to use the admin userids in a condition, such as:

```
var uname = User.Identity.GetUserId() 

if uname == 'user1@email.com', uname== 'user2@email.com'  {  $('#myModal').modal()  }
```

This is for a quick proof of concept only. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with fullcalendar directly. Please re-tag with more relevant technologies.

Comment: Thanks. But it does. We are try trying to modify the fullcalendar app to introduce user-based modal window security

Comment: FullCalendar is a front-end only technology. It's just some JavaScript in a web page. You cannot add security to that directly. Security must be done with a back-end. You need some back-end technology to control what users can and can't do. Your title says you want to "make the calendar read-only"...well the calendar _is_ read-only by default, in the sense that the "editable" and similar settings are off by default.

Comment: But even if they are switched on, any changes made will only stay within the user's browser, unless you have written code to send things to your server when certain events happen in the calendar (e.g. creating or editing an event, for example). So if you want security, it's those backend endpoints which you need to secure, to ensure no-one can send data to them without the correct permissions. That would be the case whether you had a calendar UI (such as fullCalendar) on the front-end, or just some HTML forms or something.

Comment: You also said "We would like to make the modal window (AddEditForm) hidden for all non-admins"...well fullcalendar doesn't implement any kind of modal functionality itself. So again, that's nothing to do with fullCalendar either. It sounds like your application, whatever it is, needs to check the permissions of the user when you're loading the UI view, and not provide the add/edit button to the user if they're not allowed to use it. And then also secure the endpoint which receives data from that modal, in case anyone manages to override or bypass the UI (which in a browser, isn't that hard).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, appreciate it